# Unable to model bind ajax JSON to complex object

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've looked up a couple of examples on how to bind JSON data to a complex object but there are some issues with mine.

First, here are the relevant functions:

```
function populateEligibilityDropdown() {
    var selectedMember = $("#SelectedMember_Value").val();
    var selectedMemberName = $("#SelectedMember_Value option:selected").text();

    var memberData = { "Name" : selectedMemberName };

    if (!fieldIsEmpty(selectedMember)) {
        hide(".selectPathSection, .allSectionsContainer, #reviewSubmissionBtn");
        showSpinner();

        var errorFunc = function (data) {
            processAjaxRequestError(data, "#SelectedMember_Value");
        };

        makeAjaxRequest(
            $("#GetAwardElegibiltyUrl").val(),
            "POST",
            JSON.stringify(AddAntiForgeryToken(memberData)),
            processGetAwardEligibilitySuccess,
            errorFunc,
            removeSpinner
        );
    }
}

function makeAjaxRequest(url, method, data, successFunction, errorFunction, alwaysFunction, promiseFunction) {
    $.ajax({
        "url": url,
        "type": method,
        "data": data,
        "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        "success": successFunction,
        "error": errorFunction
    }).always(alwaysFunction).then(promiseFunction);
}

AddAntiForgeryToken = function (data) {
    data.__RequestVerificationToken = $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
    return data;
};
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult GetAwardElegibilty(MemberIdentification member)
{ ... }
```

The member object has the types of `string Name` and `MemberID Id`. Id has a subfield called `Value` that is supposed to be set.

I've tried a couple of different ways:

1) Working solution is to separate the POST action into `GetAwardEligibility(MemberID id, string name)` and that binds correctly along with ValidatingAntiForgeryToken.

2) `JSON.stringify` as shown above and add `contentType` does not work because the AntiForgeryToken doesn't get picked up. It doesn't even hit the Action.

3) If I simply remove the AntiForgeryToken with the same setup as 2), I don't see any binding occurring even for the simplest case of just populating the Name.

Is this a problem with how the MemberIdentification class is setup?

Comment: What is your `AddAntiForgeryToken()` method?

Comment: Added that method. Basically appends the antiforgery token value to the json object.